# How to avoid page refresh while using selectOneChoice

Tags: oracle-adf, jdeveloper

I am working on JDeveloper 11g Release 2. I am having `af:input text` elements and `af:selectonechoice` elements in my form. The problem is with `af:selectonechoice` element. After selecting a value from this choice list, it refreshes the values of other elements. I mean the values of af:inputtext are lost or the fields becomes empty.

The code for af:selectonechoice is as follows:

```
    <af:selectOneChoice label="User Permission" id="soc" 
      value="#{row.bindings.UserPermission.inputValue}" 
      autoSubmit="true" valueChangeListener="#{SomeBean.setSomeValue}">
        <af:selectItem label="Administrator" value="ADMIN" id="si1"/>
        <af:selectItem label="Manager" value="MANAGER" id="si2"/>
        <af:selectItem label="Employee" value="EMPLOYEE" id="si3"/>
    </af:selectOneChoice>
```

Below is the code for input text:

```
    <af:inputText value="XXX" label="XXX" id="id3" readOnly="true" partialTriggers="soc" >
    </af:inputText>
```

Only the above inputText has partialtriggers. This works fine. Also I am sure that other input elements not having any partial triggers. Why the other input elements also being updated. Any ideas regarding this.

**EDIT:**

```
    <af:column sortProperty="#{bindings.TasksView1.hints.TaskNo.name}" 
      sortable="true" headerText="Task No" id="c2">
        <af:inputText value="#{row.bindings.TaskNo.inputValue}"
        label="#{bindings.TasksView1.hints.TaskNo.label}" id="id3"
        partialTriggers="soc">
    </af:inputText>
   </af:column>
```

And Code for ValueChangeLister is:

```
    public void generateTaskNo(ValueChangeEvent valueChangeEvent){   
    DCBindingContainer dcBindings = (DCBindingContainer)BindingContext.getCurrent().getCurrentBindingsEntry();
    DCIteratorBinding iterBind = (DCIteratorBinding)dcBindings.get("TasksView1Iterator");            
    valueChangeEvent.getComponent().processUpdates(FacesContext.getCurrentInstance());
    String task_code = (String)iterBind.getCurrentRow().getAttribute("USERPERMISSION");
    task_code = task_code +'-';
    String task_no = (String)iterBind.getCurrentRow().getAttribute("TaskNo");
    task_code = task_code + task_no;         
    iterBind.getCurrentRow().setAttribute("TaskNo", task_code );
```

}

Here i am getting the SelectOneChoice value and Input text value[with id 'id3' ]. Based on the selected choice's value[Admin,manager,employee] i will set the value[TaskNo] in that input text. This should not affect other input fields in the form. But the problem is all other input fields are also updating and losing their previous values. I am sure those input fields don't have any partial triggers.

Comment: What is the real code for `inputText`, the value attribute? When updating the soc, your inputText should display the value XXX. Also are you sure about row.bindings, the EL should be `#{bindings.UserPermission.inputValue}`

Comment: @Sydney this is a form with multiple rows and hence EL should be #{row.bindings.UserPermission.inputValue}.

Comment: @Sydney I have added real code for inputText as well as for my ValueChangeListener. Please see the EDIT part.

Comment: Hi anybody there to sort out this issue.. I have edited the post and put complete code..

Answer (score 0):

Your select one choice (SOC) set as auto submit = true. Then any element had partial triggers for SOC, Then that elements get refreshed. element SOC submit his value to server and other elements listen that value. listening elements needs to refreshed for update his value for SOC

Answer (score 0):

The solution for this is if you use select one choice component with list of values you want store the id in database. For suppose your storage "ID" datatype consist integer but in database storage column datatype  consist Varchar then soc components automatically refreshed when click save.so let you check the db column and list of values(lov) store value.